# Non-negative solution to a underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have an underdetermined linear system (more unknown that equations) Ax=b where both b and x represent probabilities.

Im currently using ALGLIB (rmatrixsolvels) to find a least square solution but it sometimes returns a vector x containing negative values.

Considering there should be an infinite number of solution to an underdetermined system, how do I go about finding a non-negative solution (all entries in x should be nonnegative since I am looking for probabilities)?

Im no mathematician (programmer) so if I have misunderstood anything or asking the wrong sort of question please let me know.

Also since I am doing this in .NET and I dont have a set input of A and b I cant use MATLAB etc.

Comment: That's a standard linear programming problem. You are looking for a feasible solution of a problem $Ax = b, x \ge 0$, where $A$ is the matrix of coefficients of your system and $x$ is a solution vector. So these are your search terms: "feasible solution, linear programming, .NET". Yes, there are usually infinitely many solutions, but only finitely many with a maximal number of zero entries.

Comment: So there is no "easy" way of getting a non-negative solution from the general solution I got from the Least Square Solution?

Comment: No, finding a feasible solution is as "difficult" as finding an optimal solution. It can be done in polynomial time, though. And I am sure there are canned routines to do that. The ALGLIB subpackage to use would be minbleic.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope I will manage from here. Also if you put this into an answer I would mark it correct as it is what I was looking for but I just dont seem to know how to upvote / mark a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a standard linear programming problem. You are looking for a feasible solution of a problem $Ax=b, x \ge 0$, where $A$ is the matrix of coefficients of your system and $x$ is a solution vector. Yes, there are usually infinitely many solutions, but only finitely many with a maximal number of zero entries.

Finding a feasible solution is as "difficult" as finding an optimal solution. It can be done in polynomial time, though. And I am sure there are canned routines to do that. The ALGLIB subpackage to use would be *minbleic*.